# why is "LD_QUEUE_AVAILABLE" state in this code used

Tags: c, queue

```
  if (LD_QUEUE_FULL != queue->queue_status){
/* prcess queue tail */
if ((LD_QUEUE_EMPTY == queue->queue_status)|| (LD_NO_DATA == queue->queue_status)){
  /* Set status of queue */
   if (TRANSMISSION == direction)
    queue->queue_status = LD_QUEUE_AVAILABLE;
   else
   queue->queue_status = LD_DATA_AVAILABLE;
} else {
/* Check if queue size equal to queue tail */
  if (queue->queue_max_size == queue->queue_tail + 1){
    queue->queue_tail = 0;
  } else {
    queue->queue_tail++;
  }
}
/* copy data to queue */
for (i=0; i<8; i++){
  queue_data[queue->queue_tail][i] = data[i];
}
/* update queue status */
queue->queue_current_size++;
if (queue->queue_current_size >= queue->queue_max_size){
    queue->queue_status = LD_QUEUE_FULL;
}
```

}

Tx queue has "LD_QUEUE_AVAILABLE" state and 
Rx queue has "LD_DATA_AVAILABLE"state.

In this code example, i thought that there was no reason to use "AVAILABLE" state

because when queue has state of "NO_DATA" or "EMPTY" then it must be available and some task can just use it not checking if it is "AVAILABLE"
(well actually those two state(LD_QUEUE~, LD_DATA~) does not present in the whole project rather, it was just defined.)

Is there any reason for queue must has a "AVAILABLITY STATE" ???

Comment: It indicates whether the queue is full, empty, or somewhere in between.

Comment: right. queue must have a state between empty and full. it would be useful when it comes to watch state from different software components. what i didn't understand was that I thought there would be no problem to put data and manage queuing when there is only 2 different state which is empty and full in terms of queuing operation. thanks anyway

Comment: Re "*when there is only 2 different state which is empty and full*", There aren't just two states. The negation of empty is not full.

Comment: Well, there are only 2 states for a 1-element queue. Considering whether a 1-element queue is _useful_ might help understand why the 3rd state is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needs to check if the queue is full or not (two states).

The code needs to check if the queue is empty or not (two states).

```
                 | Full            |
                 +--------+--------+
                 | No     | Yes    |
--------+--------+--------+--------+
 Empty  | No     | 0      | 1      |
        +--------+--------+--------+
        | Yes    | 2      | 3      |
--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

That's a total of four states (0, 1, 2, 3).

If the queue can't ever be both full and empty, then one of the states (3) is impossible, so we're left with three states.

```
                            | queue->queue_status
                            +--------------------+-------------------
 State                      | Tx queue           | Rx queue
----------------------------+--------------------+-------------------
 0 (Not full and not empty) | LD_QUEUE_AVAILABLE | LD_DATA_AVAILABLE
 1 (Full and not empty)     | LD_QUEUE_FULL      | ?
 2 (Not full and empty)     | LD_QUEUE_EMPTY     | LD_NO_DATA
```

One could use two boolean variables instead of a three-value "enum", but that wouldn't change the number of states.

---

> *because when queue has state of "NO_DATA" or "EMPTY" then it must be available*

Yes, but it can also be available (for queueing) when `queue->queue_status` is neither of those.

> *can just use it not checking if it is "AVAILABLE"*

Ah, but you do. You just don't have to use the constant to do so.

- A queue is available for dequeuing when in state 0 or in state 1.
  This can be checked using `queue->queue_status != LD_QUEUE_EMPTY`
- A queue is available for queuing when in state 0 or in state 2.
  This can be checked using `queue->queue_status != LD_QUEUE_FULL`

Both checks check if the queue is in state 0 because the negation of empty isn't full. But as you can see, checking for state 0 can done without using the constants `LD_QUEUE_AVAILABLE` and `LD_DATA_AVAILABLE` except when setting the state.

So, the fact that the constants are not used anywhere else doesn't mean that nothing checks for that state.